# Is using a Web API as dataprovider for a website efficient?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-web-api, connection, asp.net-webpages

I was thinking about setting up a project with Web API. Basically build the API first and program the web site using this API.

Although it's sound promising I was wondering:
If I separate the logic in a nice way, I might end up retrieving data on a web-page through multiple API call's, which in turn are multiple connections with the server with all the overhead etc..

For example, if I use, let's say 8 different API call's on one page, I can't imagine it won't have an impact on the web-page's performance.

So, have I misunderstood something? Or is this kind of overhead negligible - or does the need for multiple call's indicates that the design is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One aspect is that you can display the page to the end user very very fast . Once the page is loaded, use Jquery  async calls and any Javscript template tool (like angularjs or mustacheJs) to call the web api simultaneously to build the client page views.

I have used this approach in multiple project and experience of the user is tremendous.

Comment: hello, can i see any of your project to understand the user experience? I am planning to make website using web API and angularJS

Answer (score 2):

Well, we did it. Web API server providing the REST access to all the data. Independent *UI Clients* consuming it as the only access-point to underlying peristence.

The first request takes some time. It is significantly longer. It must init all the UI Client stuff, and get the least needed data from a server. (Menu, user, access rights, metadata...list-view data)

**The point, the real advantage, is hidden in the second, the third**... request. Lot of stuff is already there on a UI Client. And even, if this is requested again, caching (Server, Client, both) could be introduced.

So, this would mean more requests (at least during the UI Client start up)... but it does not imply ... slower application.

**The maintenance benefit is hidden** *(maybe it is not hidden, it should be obvious)* in the **Separation of Concern**. On the server, we are no longer solving the issue, where to place the user data handling, the base-controller or child-controller... should there by the Master-page, the Layout-controller...

Solved. We are taking care about single, specific stuff, published via REST. One method, one business operation. And that's the dream if we'd like to keep that application alive and be the repairman and extender.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern browsers support 6-8 parallel connections to the same site. So you do have to be careful about that. Unless you are connecting to that many separate systems, I would try to reduce the number of connections. Or ensure the calls are called asynchronously by different events to reduce the chance of parallel connections.

Answer (score 1):

Making a series of HTTP calls to obtain data for your page will have an overhead. Only testing will tell you how that might impact in your scenario.

There is little point using Web API just because you can. You should have a legitimate reason for building a RESTful API. Even then, if it is primarily for your own consumption, design it to deliver a ViewModel for each page in one call.